# Notification permission after user login in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.ios, notifications

I wanted to move the notification permission after the user logs in but it always shows up at the startup of the app for iOS.

AppDelegate.cs

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    // other code here
    ......

   InitializeAppCenter();
}

void InitializeAppCenter()
{
     AppCenter.Start(myAppSecret, typeof(Push));
    // app center initialization
   ......

   
      this.pushNotificationServiceDelegate = new PushNotificationDelegate();
      UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this.pushNotificationServiceDelegate;
    
 }
```

PushNotificationDelegate.cs

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(PushNotificationDelegate))]
namespace Test.iOS.DependencyServices
{
    public class PushNotificationDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, INotificationPermission
    {

     public bool didReceiveNotificationInForeground { get; set; }

    public void Request()
    {
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
        {
            // Ask the user for permission to get notifications on iOS 10.0+
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(
                   UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound,
                   //UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound,
                   (approved, error) => {

                       if (approved)
                           InvokeOnMainThread(UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications);
                   });
        }
        else if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
        {
            // Ask the user for permission to get notifications on iOS 8.0+
            var notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(
                    UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
                    new NSSet());

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
        }
    }

   public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
   {
      //.....
   }


   }
}
```

Supposedly it should register only the delegate and shows a permission authorization for notification ONLY when Request method is called via dependency service.

After the user login I use the dependency service `INotificationPermission` request method . but nothing shows up because the notification permission authorization was asked from the startup.

Right now I am using AppCenter push for notifications.
How to move notification permission from startup and call only when necessary?

Comment: Hi , do you have a try with disable Push when start app and re-open later when neccessary ? I'm not sure this will work , you can have a try : [Enable or disable Push at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/xamarin-ios#enable-or-disable-push-at-runtime) . In general of a native ios notification, you can register notification later when necessary ,such as this doc by calling [RegisterForRemoteNotifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/azure-services/azure-notification-hub#register-for-notifications-with-apns)

Comment: I manage to make it work by moving the  AppCenter.Start(myAppSecret, typeof(Push)) in side the request method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who will encounter these using AppCenter Push. Moving the `AppCenter.Start(myAppSecret, typeof(Push))` inside the `Request()` did the work.